# Being warned that there are programs open before logging out

Tags: gnome, 19.04, workspaces

I normally use one workspace for all my windows, but occasionally I have too many windows cluttering my desktop, so I spit them on two or more workspaces.

However, since I rarely use workspaces, it regularly happens that when I'm about to log out or shutdown my PC, I close all programs on the visible workspace and forget about the others with the consequences of files not being saved, etc.

Is there a way to receive a warning that there are programs open before the system logs me off or shuts down? Or is there some Gnome extension or workaround you might think of?

Comment: Firefox complains that it was not shut down properly. Libreoffice opens up the "recover files" dialog, etc. so no, not really.

Answer (score 1):

**Credit**: This answer is based on a script found [here](https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=508). It is for x11 systems, not Wayland, and requires that *wmctrl* be installed.

The first image shows Ubuntu 19.04 with several applications open and on various desktops:

[image: Applications and wmctrl output]

The output of `wmctrl -l` in the terminal next to the dock lists eight open applications on various desktops.

From top to bottom:

1 Firefox (with more than one tab open)
2 GNOME terminal
3 GNOME Settings
4 Gedit with an unsaved file open
5 LibreOffice Writer with an unsaved file open
6 Geany with an unsaved file open
7 Konsole with `man man` running
8 Kate (partially seen) with an unsaved file open

While the dock shows that several applications are open irrespective of their location, it's possible users may have chosen to autohide the dock.

On running the script, which I bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, applications that don't need to interact with the user are shut down immediately. In the image below, *gnome-terminal* and *gnome-settings* have already been shut down. What remains (as seen in the dock) are applications needing the user to make a decision.

The next image shows a stack of **native** dialog windows for open applications allowing users to decide whether to save their work in each application or not. In particular, LibreOffice Writer closed this way will not present a "Recovery" prompt the next time it's started.

[image: Applications needing instructions]

In this example, the last decision is whether to close Firefox. Again, the GUI is that of Firefox itself, thereby ensuring a clean closure.

[image: Closing Firefox cleanly]

---

The script (based on the BunsenLabs link):

```
#!/bin/bash
# close_all_windows
# depends on wmctrl
# johnraff's close windows before shutdown from https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=508

windows_list=($(wmctrl -l | awk ' { print $1 } '))

for i in $windows_list
do
    wmctrl -i -a $i
    wmctrl -i -c $i
done
```

---

It generates a list of open windows along with the desktops they're on. The window ID's are then passed to *wmctrl* which raises each window and then causes the parent application to ask the user for guidance.

If this approach is suitable, just add `shutdown` on a new line to the script. That will shutdown the system after one minute. Alternatively, choose some other value from `man shutdown`.