# Cancel logout / shutdown and warn user when a condition is met

Tags: gnome, shutdown, logout, 23.10

This question may be thought of being a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181047/being-warned-that-there-are-programs-open-before-logging-out) or any similar others, but I am asking the other way around.

When there are other console sessions on the same desktop, GNOME will warn you about them when you try to *shut down* the system. I want a somehow similar functionality in the *GUI **Logout*** process, so that when a special condition (e.g. a non-zero return code from a script) is met, the logout process will **warn the user and cancel the logout/shutdown**, instead of blindly logging out and **terminating all processes started from this session**.

Is there any easy method to modify the GNOME logout & shutdown process normally started by the user from the top right menu?